# Python - Convex Hull OSError in scipy and skimage

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

Some problem appears when T'm trying to use example of creating convex_hull

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.morphology import convex_hull_image
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage.util import invert

# The original image is inverted as the object must be white.
image = invert(data.horse())

chull = convex_hull_image(image)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].set_title('Original picture')
ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

ax[1].set_title('Transformed picture')
ax[1].imshow(chull, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax[1].set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

OSError: Failed to open file b'C:\\Users\\\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scipy-1alpxmub'
```

or

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial

print (points)
df = subset[['lat','lng']].sort_values('lat')
df=df.values
df
hull = ConvexHull(df)
#hull = sp.spatial.qhull.Delaunay(df).convex_hull

OSError: Failed to open file b'C:\\Users\\\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scipy-v_autexa'
```

I'm on Windows 10 x64 with python 3 from Anaconda, using it through Jupyter Notebooks. Worth to mention that I've already re-installed scipy and skimage.

Does anyone know solution to this?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for mentioning typo.

Comment: The first one (only one tested) works for me on windows and linux (anaconda). So there is probably something broken with your install. Maybe try a clean anaconda install.